# React Native scroll interaction blocks tap/touch events

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios, react-native-scrollview

I'm using a bunch of ScrollViews in my Expo React Native application, and I've noticed that whenever the ScrollView animation is still happening, I am unable to tap any TouchableHighlights or TouchableOpacity elements until the animation has fully stopped.

Is this type of blocking expected behaviour, and is there any way to circumvent this? Running on iOS.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this? I am also stuck in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use like this??

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
    // all stuff here
</ScrollView>;
```

Use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` and set it to `always`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Just to clarify, this has nothing to do with the keyboard